# trying to assign passwords where empty but overriding users passwords. My fix gets invalid Hash error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, bcrypt, password-encryption, change-password

I'm sure this may be something obvious but I'm quite new to Bcrypt and am trying to build an app where I am uploading many users whose emails I have but no passwords - I want to assign random passwords to users so that they can click on 'forgot password' to set a new password. However my method for setting the random password is overwriting the new password when saving. The fixes I have found on here are giving me an 'Invalid Hash' error. Any help much appreciated.
Code below:

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token, :user_params
before_save   :downcase_email, :downcase_role
after_save :set_password_if_nil  
before_create :create_activation_digest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are uploading the users means you are creating some new records so instead of `after_save` which runs on both `create` and `update` you can use `after_create`. So this will run only on creating the new records. Hope this helps.